# Podio Photo Upload Deleting Old Photos

Tags: podio

I have updating items using podio PodioItem::update and it is working with all fields,
Whenever I update photo field and upload new photos old photos got removed and new photos are added, I need a solution for this if I upload new photos old photos should also remain in podio.
Here is the code.
I am attaching screenshot [Here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oia8X.png) added new photos but deleting old photos

$updatepodioproperty = $this->podioPropertyUpdate($ArrayPic);

```
    $numberOfPics = count([$ArrayPic][1]);
    $arrayFile = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfPics; $i++)
    {
        $ur = $uploadPath.$ArrayPic[$i];
        $goFile = PodioFile::upload($ur, $ArrayPic[$i]);
        $fileID = $goFile->file_id;
        array_push($arrayFile,$fileID);

    }  PodioItem::update($itemIdd, array(
        'fields' => array(
            "photos" => $arrayFile,
  )
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

So when you are uploading new files, and then running the update item call you are actually replacing all of the files on Podio. You will want to run  the [Get Item](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-22360) and iterate through the files there to check if anything already exists and add those to your `$arrayFile` to the existing set of files.